# Which module has Data.DOM.Simple

Tags: purescript

Im reading Purescript by example book and jt mentions Data.DOM.Simple module. purescripts pursuit seems to be broken..does anyone knows which module Data.DOM.Simple is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It belongs to [purescript-simple-dom](https://github.com/aktowns/purescript-simple-dom), but it's not on pursuit as it hasn't been updated to keep up with the new versions of purescript.